# Android: creating an alarm which runs in background from startup

Tags: android, database, alarm

I am trying to make an application which sets off an alarm at a specific time based off data inserted into the database, and I have ran into a number of problems

The first problem with the code I have written is that within my RunningInBackground class file, "context" throws up a "Cannot resolve symbol 'context'" error.

The second issue I have ran into is that I am unsure as to how I compare all data within my "Date" column with the current date. I have been able to get the current date, but not check for a match with a date within my database. I wish to do this within my "AlarmCheckDateAndTime" class file.

PhoneHasBooted.class
    public class PhoneHasBooted extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
    final static String TAG = "BootCompleteReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Starting service...");
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RunningInBackground.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

RunningInBackground.class

```
public class RunningInBackground extends IntentService {

    public RunningInBackground() {
        super("RunningInBackground");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onHandleIntent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmCheckDateAndTime.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,  0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60); // first time
        long frequency= 60 * 1000; // in ms
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), frequency, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

AlarmCheckDateAndTime.class

```
public class AlarmCheckDateAndTime{
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;



public static void main (String[] args){
    Date ThisDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    String DateChecker = formatter.format(ThisDate);

    Date ThisTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat timeformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String TimeChecker = formatter.format(ThisTime);
    do AlarmCount
    if(DateChecker ==  )


}
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first issue, `IntentService` extends `Context`, and it doesn't seem that you have a variable `context` set.    In `RunningInBackground`, just replace every instance of `context` with `this` or `this.getApplicationContext()` to use the Application Context.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help with the RunningInBackground class file!